# Have remote X app open without manual "placement" on my local display

Tags: ssh, remote, window-manager, x-windows

I am running X on my local machine and then using `ssh -Y username@remotemachine` to connect to a remote Debian server. Once logged in to this remote Debian server I type `iceweasel` at the command line prompt. When this app starts I get the rubber-band outline that wants me to place the window before it starts.

I want to be able to start `iceweasel` and have it open up on my local display without waiting for me to manually place it anywhere. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

twm autoplacement can be set in your ~/.twmrc file with "RandomPlacement".

e.g.,

```
$ cat ~/.twmrc
RandomPlacement

$
```

twm is rough though, there are a lot of things you cannot configure.  "man twm" has a lot of good information.

Answer (score 0):

A work colleague informed me that auto-placement is a function of the windows manager; the window manager I was using (twm) does not auto-place. So, I simply changed to a different windows manager that *does* auto-place, solving the problem.